# how to print the microsecond symbol in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to print the microsecond symbol in C, but I don't get any data in the output.

```
printf("Micro second = \230");
```

I also tried using 
int i = 230;

```
printf("Character %c", i);
```

but in vain! Any pointers?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What happened when you tried that? Did you get any output at all? What did the output show?

Comment: I am working on a Mac(Snow Leopard 10.6)

Comment: What encoding are you using with the Terminal.app?

Comment: This isn't why you get *nothing* (that would be the UTF-8 issue, as explained below) but `\nnn` in a string interprets `nnn` as an *octal* number. Decimal 230 is octal 346 is hex E6; octal 230 is decimal 152 is hex 98.  In [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), which is what you seem to have been expecting based on using 230 for µ, code point 152 (decimal) is ÿ.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That depends entirely on the character encoding used by the console you're using.  If you're using Linux or Mac OS X, then most likely that encoding is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  The UTF-8 encoding for µ (Unicode code point U+00B5) is 'C2 B5' (two bytes), so you can print it like this:

```
printf("Micro second = \xC2\xB5");  // UTF-8
```

If you're on Windows, then the default encoding used by the console is [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), then µ is encoded as 0xE6, so you would have to do this:

```
printf("Micro second = \xE6");  // Windows, assuming CP 437
```

Comment: The OSX terminal defaults to UTF-8 but can be chnaged

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that's true.  If you can detect what encoding the terminal is using (there's probably a way, but I don't know what that is), then you could use something like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to convert the sequence into the terminal's encoding at runtime.

Comment: CP437 uses `\xE6` for µ (== 230); `\xB2` is ▒.

Comment: @Zack: Whoops, no idea how that happened, I must have severely misread Wikipedia <_<.

Comment: For the micro character on at least Win7 Tahoma Western, try alt-0181 via the numeric keypad, or type out \xB5. Both methods worked using log4cxx and displayed properly in Apache's Chainsaw. Alt-0181 also displayed properly in VS2010. Also worked in this SO editor typed here: µ.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the standards-sanctioned way to print it in C:

```
printf("%lc", L'\u00b5');
```

If you're happy assuming UTF-8, though, I'd just hard-code `"µ"`.

Comment: +1, but I think you have a mismatch. Either you use `%ls` as a format string or `L'\u00b5'`.

Comment: seems like I got µ

Answer (score 1):

Since you work on Mac OS, you can rest assured that the terminal uses UTF-8. Therefore, bring up the characters palette (Edit -> Special characters...), find the microsecond symbol there, and put it right into your string.

```
int main()
{
    printf("µs\n");
}
```

It will work as long as your source file is UTF-8 too. Otherwise, you'll need to find the code point for it (which should also be indicated in the characters palette). Mouse over the character to find its UTF-8 value (and excuse my French system):
[image: Example of the Mac OS special characters palette showing a code point]

This means you can use `printf("\xc2\xb5")` as an encoding-independant replacement for the character itself.

Comment: Or just do option-m to produce the µ.

Comment: While that may work, it is not portable, since µ is not contained in the basic source character set.  With GCC, it might choose a different source character set if, say your `LANG` environment variable is set to certain values; you would need to override this with the `-finput-charset=UTF-8` option.  With other compilers, who knows.

Comment: @Stephen Canon I'd think it doesn't work on all keyboard layouts, though; and also, the special characters palette gives you other interesting informations.

Answer (score 0):

```
  printf("%c", 230);
```

works for me. <s>I think this is OS dependent though.</s> It is encoding dependent (thanks zneak). I'm on Windows.

Comment: It rather is encoding-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found the solution based on  [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

```
"\xB5"
```

I just included that code into a string and it worked for me.

My environnement: Windows, C++. I was trying to convert a string to display in SFML.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mix of C and C++14 for a work project, here's what worked for me:

```
printf("Micro second symbol = \xC2\xB5");
```

\xB5, and \230 produced ▒ on my output. My project equipment is apparently is picky as I tried it with elsewhere with some online IDE's and a version of Xcode on Mac, all worked fine.

Could be if you're trying to print elsewhere besides console, say like to an LCD screen, then you're screen would have to be programmed (created and mapped to xyz...) to include that character. Though from my experience that varies wildly depending on what you're creating.

Comment: You might explain that C2 B5 is the UTF-8 encoding for Unicode code point 181, the `MICRO SIGN` symbol `µ`.  Furthermore, your answer is no better than the accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5060616/4593267